# How can I use LIKE operation on a parameter?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
def SupplierLookup(Name):
  cursor = conn.cursor()

  SQL = '''SELECT CompanyName, ContactName, Phone
         FROM Supplier
         WHERE CompanyName = ?'''
  for row in cursor.execute(SQL, (Name,)).fetchall():
      print('Supplier: ' + row[0] + ' ContactPerson: ' + row[1] + ' Phone: ' + row[2])
```

How can i do it so if you type 'Exotic' in the parameter it will display the full word which is 'Exotic Liquid' Ive tried to use LIKE operation but it keeps failing

Comment: add a sql wildcard % to the string

Comment: So CompanyName LIKE %?%

Comment: no `(Name + '%',)` as parameter and LIKE as Operatpor in the query